# Fehlermeldung: AndroidRuntime(20941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

while I test my app, I get the follow error in the Android-Studio-Consol:
Whenever I try to run my application, an error is showing up in the LogCat. 
[image]

This is my code in MainActivity.java
but dont know whats error

```
package com.categorysms.ir.categorysms;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // declare properties
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           @Overrid
          public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }        });
        // list the drawer items
        ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];

        drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_copy, "Create");
        drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh, "Read");
        drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_action_share, "Help");

        // Pass the folderData to our ListView adapter
        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // set the item click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // for app icon control for nav drawer
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // navigation drawer click listener
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new CreateFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ReadFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new HelpFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    // to change up caret
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line number `87` in `MainActivity.java` ?

Comment: Try replacing instances of `getActionBar()` with `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the support version of the `Toolbar`, (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) so you need to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

I would check out this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for more info

Comment: iam use  getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() but see error getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: Then `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null. Check to see if the toolbar is null when you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` How is the toolbar defined in your XML?

Comment: iam debug program but this code line see error  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    /   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);